# How can i write a list to a new excel workbook?

Tags: python, excel, list, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

So i have a problem, i have a list with full of datas in it from other excel workbooks and i want to write it to a new excel. I made it half succesfull, my code only writes the list's first element. How can i write tha datas row by row?
This is my code so far:

```
import glob as gl
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import xlsxwriter

files = gl.glob(r"<path>*.xlsm")
for file in files:
    lst = []
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
    s = wb.active
    a = s['C2'].value
    lst.append(a)
    b = s['E2'].value
    lst.append(b)
    c = s['C3'].value
    lst.append(c)


    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('<name>.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

    row = 1
    column = 0
    for item in lst:
        worksheet.write(row,column,item)
        column += 1
    workbook.close()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample for ```lst```?

Comment: @PouyaEsmaeili ['heyho', 'hohoo', 'juhuu'], something like this

Comment: If you stick with using openpyxl, and I see no reason from your code why not to, you can just `ws.append(lst)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to gather all files in a list, so:

```
all_lists = []
for file in files:
    lst = []
    wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
    s = wb.active
    a = s['C2'].value
    lst.append(a)
    b = s['E2'].value
    lst.append(b)
    c = s['C3'].value
    lst.append(c)
    all_lists.append(lst)
```

After the above snippet you'll have all the read files in `all_files`
Now as an example, suppose:

```
all_files = [['heyho', 'hohoo', 'juhuu'],
             ['heyho1', 'hohoo1', 'juhuu1'],
             ['heyho2', 'hohoo2', 'juhuu2']]
```

You can write each element in a row by the following snippet:

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0  # initial row
for item in all_files:
    column = 0  # column resets for each row
    for i in item:
        worksheet.write(row, column, i)
        column += 1
    row += 1
workbook.close()
```

Comment: i guess my composition was bad, i have like 200 .xlsm files and i have to put the datas(cell values) to a new excel, so 1 have 200 elements in my list and i want to write it to a new excel row by row.The  ['heyho', 'hohoo', 'juhuu'] has to be one row and so on.

Comment: You mean you have a list of lists and you'd like to write them all in a worksheet row by row? Each *.xlsm file will be corresponded to a row in the result? That mean each *.xlsm is a list to be written in a row.

Comment: Exactly.I would write that before, just didn't know how to express myself, sorry.

Comment: I've just updated my answer, check again @ficsorkrsiztian